# Django, filter records from model method?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to filter records using a model method but am unsure how to implement it in the view.

Should it be done in this way, or completely in the view in some other manor?

Here's my model below:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    msg_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    added = models.DateTimeField('added')

    def about_cats(self):
        matches = ['cat', 'kitty', 'meow']
        return any(s in self.message for s in matches)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message
```

Comment: Is it needed/useful anywhere other than the view?

Comment: Also, `return any(...)`.

Comment: @ignacio just in view.py. added return.

Comment: what is `tweet_content` here?

Comment: @karthikr that should be 'message' fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to filter the queryset object, you can do something like this in your view:

```
from django.db.models import Q
matches = ['cat', 'kitty', 'meow']
messages = Message.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(message__contains=match) for match in matches)))  #Or use icontains if you want a case insensitive match.
```

Comment: You need to import Q :) `from django.db.models import Q`

Answer (score 1):

The filter should be a method of a MessageManager. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/

Comment: I did try this earlier, putting the method within MessageManager class then in my model function:

objects = MessageManager()

and then in my view:
msg_list = Message.objects


on the page the results are not filtered